# Растянуть изображения по ширине экрана

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите, что нужно написать, чтобы картинки растянулись по ширине всего экрана? 
[[image: то что есть]
[image: как должно быть]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не понятно какой должен быть результат..

Comment: картинки дожны быть растянуты по ширине,но вместо этого появляются  промежутки

Comment: @ChromeChrome что именно не работает при `width:100%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div.container {
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
div.row, div.col-sm-12 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div.col-sm-4 {    
    width:33.333%; /* на 3-и дива, 25% на 4-е дива и т.д. */
    padding:0;
}
div.col-sm-4 img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Ну как, работает?

Comment: да работает,но появляется другая проблема у первого блока слева отступ и третьего блока отступ справа

Comment: Добавте стиль на div.container как в ответе

Comment: Без изменений,если использовать div.container, как в ответе. Кстати если использовать container-fluid - работает, но появляется полоса прокрутки снизу

Comment: Попробуйте как в ответе, я его доработал.

Comment: Я побывал, но не выходит почему-то

Comment: Именно то, что есть сейчас? 
С div.row, div.col-sm-12 ? 
С width:33.333% ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31686/discussion-between-michael-vaysman-and-chromechrome).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, атрибут "Width" вам подойде:

```
 <img width="100%" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" />
```

Comment: попробовал, не работает (

Comment: @ChromeChrome, попробуйте <img style="width: 100%" ...